# Angular2/http (POST)

Tags: angular2-http

I'm a new guy on Angular 2, i get stuck on Angular Http post. I put all code [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/DnzazvOtjaSLbeHKVYOZ?p=preview)`

```js
addHero(name: string): Observable<Hero>{
        let body= JSON.stringify({name});
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept','application/json');
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        console.log(body);
        return this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, body, options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError)
        //return new Observable(name=>{id:3; name:name})
    }
```

`

When i click on Add Hero button, it throw a bug as image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg0Um.png)
Anyone know what wrong with this. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

To post data you need to create an API or simulate one. According to the docs you can only use get from a .json file.

For learning angular 2 http I would suggest setting up an in memory api as in the tutorial. See the InMemoryDataService here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

And more about how it works here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#in-mem-web-api

And the working plunker from the tutorial: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: Thanks m4ttsson, I figured it out what happened under the hood